# how to widen selection then run document.execCommand?

Tags: javascript

just to understand how the selection and range objects work on a web page, I want to select some text with the mouse, then use code to widen that selection and then mark that text as bold.

As long as the code does not touch the range, the execCommand statement is able to bold the text.  But rebuilding the range causes execCommand to have no effect.  Why is that?

here is the function I run that widens the selection range:

```js
function window_widenSelection( numChar )
{
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange( );

  var startNode = range.startContainer ;
  var startOffset = range.startOffset ;
  var endNode = range.endContainer;
  var endOffset = range.endOffset ;

  range.setStart(startNode, startOffset);
  range.setEnd(endNode, endOffset + numChar ) ;
  range.collapse(true);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}
```

Here is the full code:

```html
<!-- demonstrate how to widen selection and highlight selected text -->
  <!-- http://192.168.1.170:10080/coder/tester/contentEditable/widenSelection.html -->

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>widen selection demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p>Select some text with the mouse, then click button to make the text bold.</p>
    <div>
        <button type="button" onclick="bold_click( )">bold selected text</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button type="button" onclick="widen_bold_click( )">widen, then bold selected text</button>
    </div>

    <br>
<div id="testDiv" contenteditable="true" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" 
          autocapiatlise="off" spellcheck="false" 
          style="padding: 5px 5px; border: 1px solid black;">
        This is a test <span style="color: blue">and this is blue</span>
        and this is back to black
      </div>

  </body>

  <script>

// -------------------------- formatDoc --------------------------------
function formatDoc(sCmd, sValue)
{
  document.execCommand(sCmd, false, sValue);

  var e1 = document.getElementById('text');
  if ( e1 )
    e1.focus();
}

function bold_click( ev )
{
  formatDoc('bold') ;
}

function widen_bold_click( ev )
{
  window_widenSelection(3) ;
  formatDoc('bold') ;
}

function window_widenSelection( numChar )
{
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange( );

  var startNode = range.startContainer ;
  var startOffset = range.startOffset ;
  var endNode = range.endContainer;
  var endOffset = range.endOffset ;

  range.setStart(startNode, startOffset);
  range.setEnd(endNode, endOffset + numChar ) ;
 // range.collapse(true);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}

  </script>
  </html>
```

Comment: I would just go for the easier option. `window.getSelection()` gives you the node containing the selected text and `.toString()` will give you the selected part of the text. Then i would just replace the innerHTML of that node with `<span class="bold">` around that text. The rest is CSS.

Comment: thanks.  Looking to understand how the selection and range objects work together.

Answer (score 0):

was just a coding error.  I was collapsing the range after creating it.